# How to auto create postgresql schema (other than the default "public" one) using spring and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I want to initialize a local postgresql db using spring and hibernate, but using:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

it does not create the schema I have configured in my entity classes using `@Table(name = "table_name", schema = "schema_name")` and I get the error:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: schema "schema_name" does not exist.

Is there any way of creating the schema automatically?

Comment: try to use *flyway/liquibase* to creating/initialization.

Comment: I very much doubt that Hibernate is able to do that. The obfuscation layers usually do not support advanced features that are not available across all database systems

Comment: as someone else already pointed you can use db versioning tools to do that as `liquibase` however Spring as the option to execute SQL at boostrap time, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html `Spring Boot can automatically create the schema (DDL scripts) of your DataSource and initialize it (DML scripts). It loads SQL from the standard root classpath locations: schema.sql and data.sql, respectively`